# Is -hash enough to uniquely represent a URL?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, hash, nsstring

I'm using `hash` on an `NSString` to get an integer to uniquely represent a URL and then store it in Core Data to unique the object.

Is that enough to make sure it'll be unique? The URL string is usually 50 to 80 chars.

If it's not I'll gladly accept any suggestion to make it better!

Comment: Whats wrong with the string itself?

Comment: How many URLs will there be?

Comment: about 70 000 ? And also if I use the string itself then I would get terrible performance when doing find-or-create to update the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the hash is not enough to unique an URL. The purpose of hash is to distribute objects like for example, computing the hash table index.

With hash code you can do a fast comparison and if two objects have two different hashes they're different, if they have the same hash you gotta use compare.

Comment: Exactly, equal hashes mean only that the objects might be equal (while unequal hashes mean that the objects are definitely not equal)

Comment: @Clarisse You may want to look into a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) which all have as a sole purpose to make collisions "as impossible as possible".